# Standard Sudoku Specialized with just 2 Primes

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, sudoku, calculation-puzzle

A standard 9x9 Sudoku uses the digits 1 to 9.

You are only allowed two distinct primes to represent 1 to 9.

Find out the minimum number of characters (digits + signs) needed to construct a Sudoku puzzle with a unique solution.

Allowed signs are plus, minus, division, multiplication, factorial, and exponentiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [minimal Sudoku](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/426554/mathematicians-solve-minimum-sudoku-problem/) contains 17 digits: 2 each of seven of the nine digits, 3 of another digit, and none of the last one. (By symmetry, it doesn't matter which two digits are selected to appear 3 and 0 times in the Sudoku.)

If we select our two primes as

> 2 and 3, then we can represent the digits as $$3-2,2,3,2+2,2+3,3!,?,2\wedge3,3\times3.$$ (We omit 7 because we only need to represent *all but one* of the digits for the minimal Sudoku.)

So we choose the minimal Sudoku with

> seventeen digits filled, two each of $1,2,4,5,6,8,9$ and three of $3$.

How many symbols do we need to use then?

> Each of $1,4,5,8,9$ requires three symbols, $2$ and $3$ require only one, and $6$ requires two. So the total is $$5(2\times3)+(2\times1)+(2\times2)+(3\times1)=30+2+4+3=39.$$

Comment: Excellent !!!........

Answer (score 2):

I got it down to

> 37 symbols

Using all the same methods as @RandAlThor, but choosing a

> 17 clue sudoku with a slightly more off-balance clue distribution (1,3,4,2,1,2,0,2,2):
>
>  [image]

For double checking purposes, here's the sudoku as solved by https://sudokusolver.net/

> [image]

For further improvement, it's very likely that some digit(s), particularly those that occur twice, can be replaced by adding both a 2 and a 3, giving a sudoku that has more clues but fewer symbols. Since I cannot figure out a non-boring way to do the search for those, I'll leave it to someone else.

**EDIT**
@Oray helpfully pointed out in the comments that factorials were allowed, and OP says we can cheat with the exponentiation symbol too so here's a version with

> 29 symbols:
>
>  [image]

Comment: Very elegant...!!!

Comment: 3! instad of 3+3 makes it 35 :)

Comment: @Oray Oh, right, we were allowed to use that. Oops :-)

Comment: We can cheat a little bit..use the power notation  and omitting “^” carrot symbol..8 can be written with 2 characters..bringing it down further to 33..just a tad less than double the minimum of 17.

Comment: Given these new tricks, the latest version is probably pretty close to a hard minimum: the only 3-symbol clues occur only once each, so they cannot be replaced with anything, and replacing 2-symbol clues seems unlikely to bring the number of symbols down very much.

Comment: @Uvc, I'm probably sherlocking way too much here, but are you certain you had a specific solution in mind when you posted this puzzle? (It's kind of a requirement for posting puzzles on this the site.) Specifically, I was wondering why you would mention that 8 can be written with 2 symbols, but ignoring that 9 can, too. In any case, this was a nice puzzle, thanks for it.

Comment: Yes..nobody mentioned that..exponetiation can eliminate one sign,,..based on a particular problem and stars align using exponention and factorial it will be twofer..checked few problems from sudoku.com to work out...I was expecting around 34...thx for great discussion